# JS - IntersectionObserver - Argument 1 does not implement interface Element

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm trying to add a class 'is-visible' to all elements of a class 'module' using IntersectionObserver when they come into view on scrolling. I get the error:

> IntersectionObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface
> Element.

Javascript:

```
let modules = document.getElementsByClassName("module");

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  ([e]) => {
    let modules = document.getElementsByClassName("module");
    modules.forEach((entry) => {
      entry.classList.toggle("is-visible", e.intersectionRatio < 1);
    });
  },
  { threshold: [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1] }
);

window.addEventListener(
  "load",
  (event) => {
    observer.observe(modules);
  },
  false
);
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="hero">
    <h1>This is my hero</h1>
  </div>
  <div id='strip'>
    <div id='s1'>Option 1</div>
    <div id='s2'>Option 2</div>
    <div id='s3'>Option 3</div>
    <div id='s4'>Option 4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box" class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

  <div class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>What we do</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

  <div class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>Who we are</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

  <div class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>Mission</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

  <div class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>About us</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

  <div class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>Services</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

  <div class="module fade-in-section">
    <h2>Processes</h2>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/100" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Here's a codepen:

https://codepen.io/m-herda/pen/BazpzZM

UPDATE:
Apart from the explanation to my problem that was mentioned in the comments/answers, it looks like a lot of the code above was not necessary. The code below works fine and is much simpler.

```
const modules = document.querySelectorAll(".module");

function handleIntersection(entries) {
  entries.map((entry) => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.classList.add("is-visible");
    } else {
      entry.target.classList.remove("is-visible");
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);
  modules.forEach((m) => observer.observe(m));
});
```

Comment: The `observe` method takes in a single element, not an array of elements. You'd have to loop over the `modules` and observe every single one.

Answer (score 4):

The error you get is:

`IntersectionObserver.observe: Argument 1 does not implement interface Element.`

This clearly states that the first argument of the function `IntersectionObserver.observe` needs to be an element.
[Read the documentation of it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/observe).

In your code, you are calling `.observe` with a collection of elements.

The solution is to call it on each element you want to observe separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `getElementsByClassName("module");` to select your class use `querySelector(".module");` or `querySelectorAll(".module");` when selecting the observed element.